# Install ubuntu-desktop dependencies problem

Tags: 14.04, unity, apt

I have added this repository [ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty](https://launchpad.net/~gurqn/+archive/ubuntu/systray-trusty) to my Ubuntu 14.04.

After this I performed an `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`. But soon after I decided to remove installed packages from this repository via the Ubuntu Software Center.

One of the packages seems to be a patch in the `ubuntu-desktop` package and that's probably how I uninstalled `ubuntu-desktop`.

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu and all my conclusions are deduced from the forums I visited today trying to fix my problem. So, it seems that I have uninstalled my ubuntu-desktop package, after which I performed `apt-get auto-remove` (please, don't ask me why). This seems to be the final action which made me loose the Desktop GUI on Ubuntu.

After that, I have performed `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, `apt-get update --fix-missing`, `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, `apt-get install unity` under safemode.

The Guest Session Account had its Desktop GUI back to normal, but this is not the case with my personal Ubuntu account. It still has no Desktop GUI.

I decided to remove the `ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty` repository because it seems to provide some of the dependencies and to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity` packages but during installation I have some issues with dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity : Depends: libunity-core-6.0-9 (= 7.2.3+14.04.20140826-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
     Recommends: unity-lens-applications but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall ubuntu-desktop, unity`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` says: `ubuntu-desktop: Depends: unity, but it's not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Comment: My bad, run that command again, but without the comma. That messed it up. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that extra comma. NP :)

Comment: Any change in the output of the command?

Comment: No, APT still complains about the same dependencies. I just added the output of `apt-get install` in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19777/discussion-between-0xc0deguru-and-rpi-awesomeness).

Comment: What's `apt-cache policy libunity-core-6.0-9` saying ?

Answer (score 1):

Type these commands:

1. sudo apt-get autoclean
2. sudo apt-get clean
3. sudo dpkg --configure -a
4. sudo apt-get update

If it doesn't solve the issue, type sudo apt-get dist-upgrade as the 5th step from the above. I hope it can rectify the issue.

Comment: I did run all of the steps and didn't encountered any errors but still have the same issue. After I rebooted, I tried to run again `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` and APT reports the same error message.

Comment: You will have to remove the package libunity-core-6.0-9 and proceed with the command.

Comment: Ok, I removed `unity-services` pakage which alowed me to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity` succesfuly, but I have still the same issue: I see only icons on my desctop and a mouse coursor. The mouse context menu also works.

Comment: Reboot the system and check once.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove unity-services package which alowed me to reinstall ubuntu-desktop and unity successfully. After reboot Unity didn't start because it was disabled and probably wrongly configured. I installed CompizConfig Settings Manager which I used to enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin with. Check this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) to see how to enable Ubuntu Unity Plugin and reset it to default configuration. Issue is solved. Thank you all for your help. Happy holidays!